# Updating simple mongodb array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document in a collection named `homes` that looks like:

```
{
_id: ObjectId(someId),
...
tips: [
   {
      _id: ObjectId(someId),
      nid: Integer,
      title: "Some String"
      description: "Some Description"
   },
   ...
]
}
```

When I try to perform an update on an Object in my `Tips` array, it doesn't seem to match. Here's how I'm trying to perform the update:

```
db.collection("homes").findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: homeId, "tips.nid": nid },
    {
      $set: {
        "tips.$.description": description,
      },
    }
)
```

The result shows 0 matches, despite there being a `home` with `_id` and a `tips.nid` that matches. Am I using the wrong syntax?

Comment: need to convert `homeId` from string to object id using `ObjectId(homeId)`

Comment: I do this already :)

Comment: Test the query separately using find or countDocuments.  If there are no documents found, try testing each query predicate separately.

Answer (score 0):

you need $elemMatch like so:

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        _id: homeId,
        "tips": { $elemMatch: { nid: nid } }
    },
    {
        $set: {
            "tips.$.description": description
        }
    },
    {
        returnNewDocument: true
    }
)
```